# Integrating facebook chat API into iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS application that already using some methods of Facebook Graph API, but i need to implement sending private message to friend by Facebook from my application. As i know, there is no way to sending private messages by Graph API, but it maybe possible by help Facebook Chat API. I already read documentation but it don't help me. If anybody has some kind of example or tutorial, how to implement Facebook Chat API in iOS application, how sending requests or something, it will be very helpfull. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/IntroToFramework) which has sections on both integrating the XMPP framework into iOS and [implementing Facebook chat](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/FacebookChatHowTo). This includes working sample projects.

Facebook private messages are accessible, but seem to be read only. See this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/428).

Answer (score 3):

check this github project. they have integrated facebook api using xmppframework  https://github.com/KanybekMomukeyev/FacebookChat